# Converting CSV to JSON to send POST From React to Flask API

Tags: reactjs, json, flask, axios, papaparse

I am attempting to send a POST request to my API from my React app and am figuring out how to change a CSV from input to JSON format so no downloading needs to take place. I have seen people use Papaparse but from what I saw was that it hadn't been updated in a while so I am looking for other options.

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();// from elements property
        console.log(event.target.returns.value)
        console.log(await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/ratios', event.target.returns.value))
        setShow(true)
    };
```

If I just send like this I get a 500 error and the first line of my POST function on Flask is

```
df = request.get_json()
```

maybe there's an easier way but let me know if you have any insight or advice. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat confusing and I think it's due to your understanding of how csv and json would interact. CSV is essentially a way to send tables of data, it doesn't have an inherent key pair structure so you need to do a little work to convert it. I'm not familiar with flask specifically but it looks like `df = request.get_json()` is trying to parse what it expects to be json but is instead csv. You are right that you need to convert that. Papaparse seems like an excellent option and is still under active development. However I don't think that really matters since csv and json are formats that haven't changed in a long time so the task of converting them hasn't changed. So whether or not there has been recent development doesn't matter.

If you decided to roll your own you could probably get close by taking each row and turning that into an object then matching each row entry with a first row key label or just with saved constants. Depend on how your csvs are structured.

Comment: You make an amazing point about whether recent development matters! I completely agree and will be using that for my application.